# override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, segue

I have a table view controller that works like a news feed of images where each image has been retrieved from firebase. I want to be able to tap on each image and perform a segue to another view controller that has a table view with its own unique data of the tapped image. 
With the code I have, the `override func prepare(for:sender)` is not being called and there is no error. The unique post id is being printed in the console when the image is tapped but the Show Segue is not being performed.

Here is my code in the HomeTableViewCell:

```
protocol HomeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func goToSiteVC(postId: String)

}

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var siteImageView: UIImageView!
    var delegate: HomeTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.siteImageView_TouchUpInside))
        siteImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        siteImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @objc func siteImageView_TouchUpInside() {
        print("siteImageView_TouchUpInside")
        print(post?.id)
        if let id = post?.id {
            delegate?.goToSiteVC(postId: id)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code in HomeViewController:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var posts = [Post]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadPosts()
    }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "SiteSegue" {
                let siteVC = segue.destination as! SiteViewController
                let postId = sender as! String
                siteVC.postId = postId
                print("segue")
            }
        }
    }


extension HomeViewController: HomeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func goToSiteVC(postId: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SiteSegue", sender: postId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the "SiteVC" being displayed, and only `prepare`... is not called? Please show the code in `goToSiteVC`

Comment: Is `delegate` nil?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I've added my goToSiteVC code

Comment: `prepare(for` must be located on the top level of the class (same level as `viewDidLoad`), not be nested within `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @vadian I've connected the segue in IB and I believe my prepare(for code is correct. I've included it in the new edit of this question now

Comment: did you set cell.delegate = self in cellForRowAt in cellforowatindexpath

Answer (score 1):

The function should be out of `viewDidLoad` it must be in class scope

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var posts = [Post]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadPosts()



    }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "SiteSegue" {
                let siteVC = segue.destination as! SiteViewController
                let postId = sender as! String
                siteVC.postId = postId
                print("segue")
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I have put it outside the viewDidLoad in my xcode project, I just copied it over incorrectly here. I've edited it now, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: did you set cell.delegate = self in cellForRowAt

Comment: No I didn't!! That was it! So silly of me. Thank you so much!!